# Illegal characters in path with web.downloadstring

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to use regex to retrieve names from a website. However I get the error using "Illegal characters in path" when I run the program. Here's the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> givenNames = new List<string>();

    WebClient web = new WebClient();

    for (int i = 10000; i <= 33852; i++)
    {   
        string numberurl = i.ToString();
        string mainurl = "www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/details.aspx?view=1&id=+" + numberurl;
        String html = web.DownloadString(mainurl);

        Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"</strong>\s*(.+?)\s*&nbsp;", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        string givenName = m.Groups[1].Value;
        givenNames.Add(givenName);
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = givenNames; 
}
```

The error occurs at `String html = web.DownloadString(mainurl);`. I tried using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` but it still did not work. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you try adding `http://` to your URL?

Comment: Of course not having the protocol at the start of the path means that there _are_ illegal characters _in_ the path. Totally self explanatory error message, well done Microsoft.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to include http:// in the URL.

```
string mainurl = "http://www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/details.aspx?view=1&id=+" + numberurl;
```

Answer (score 0):

My URL was got from a API endpoint, so it was returned as a quoted string, like `"\"http://someurl.com/somefile.txt\""`. The quoted string is what was upseting WebClient when trying to download the file.

To fix it I called method `myUrl.Trim('"')` on this string, making it remove the quotes from the beginning and end of the string.

After this, the string became `"http://someurl.com/somefile.txt"` (without the inner quotes), and then the webclient was able to successfully download the file from the URL.